# Getting string inside string

Tags: java, regex

my problem is just simple. Simple to those who know RegEx well and unfortunately, I'm not.
So, please help me with this.

I have `String`. Let's say, `"java @aa@ test @bbb@"`.
What Regular Expression should I be using if the only matches I need are:

```
1. @aa@
2. @bbb@
```

I tried this expression `(@(.*)@)` but the results were:

```
1. "@aa@ bang @bb@
2. aa@ bang @bb
```

which is way too far from what I need.

P.S.
Also, I don't want matches like @@ or empty string inside these two @ signs.

Comment: should the regex match this? "java @aa bb@"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion the best option would be

```
@[^@]+@
```

which looks like:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/78ki6Mo5oGrmJH8N)

You *can* also use the non-greedy `.+?`, but when your delimiter is only a single character (in this case `@`) you should usually prefer the negated character class approach.

By the way a great resource for learning about regular expressions is [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info). It starts from the very basic and goes all the way to the very advanced. I urge you to skim through it if you're interested in learning more about regexes. Of course there is also the Java-specific Oracle [lesson on regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) as well; both are great.

---

```
String str = "java @aa@ test @bbb@";

Matcher m = Pattern.compile("@[^@]+@").matcher(str);
while (m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group());
```

```
@aa@
@bbb@
```

Comment: Removing "aa" leaving @@ alone makes the matches wrong. What regex should I use if the pattern I need is @(something SHOULD be here)@ ?

Comment: @GM-XileGM-Xile I would replace `+` with `*` and filter out the cases where there is nothing between the `@`s manually. It should only come down to checking if the length of the match is equal to 2, since you know you must always have an `@` at the start and one at the end.

Comment: I also thought of doing it manually. Anyways thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

.* is greedy. You should try .*?

If you put the ? then the reg exp will stop at the first @, otherwise it will not stop until it maches the last @ (that's greediness)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but can you give me an expression wherein there will always be a string inside these two @ signs?

Answer (score 1):

Quantifiers are by default greedy. `.*` will consume everything till the last `@`. To make it stop at the first `@`, you need to use reluctant quantifier:

```
@.+?@
```

or also a negated character class would work:

```
@[^@]+@
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I forgot to say that I don't want that there will be results like @@ . There should be something inside @@.

Comment: @GM-XileGM-Xile Just change the quantifier to `+`'

Comment: I changed the String to java @@ test @bbb@ but now the match is @@ test @. What regex should I use if I need results like "@(a String inside here)@"?

Comment: @GM-XileGM-Xile Can you post your all possible patters, and required output in those cases? You can edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

Two options: use non-greedy or use negated class.

Non-greedy is made by adding a `?` to the `.*`:

```
@(.*?)@
```

Negated class is using everything not a `@`:

```
@([^@]*)@
```

The second is faster by the way.

There's actually a third way:

```
(?<=@)[^@]*(?=@)
```

But this might be a little more difficult to understand.

---

It seems to me that you don't understand regex that much. Maybe some more explanations are needed.

`.` in regex will match any character, unless it is escaped or used in a character class where it will be treated as a literal character.

`*` in regex is a quantifier, which allows matches of the previous pattern 0 or more times; which implies that if there's nothing to match, that 'nothing' will be matched, and in your case, the nothing between the two `@` in `@@` will be matched so that you get an empty string as result.

`+` is similar to `*`, except that instead of matching 0 or more times, it matches 1 or more times, implying that it makes sure there is at least 1 character to be matched. In your case, it would make much more sense to use the second regex (with the negated class) with this quantifier: `@([^@]+)@`

`( ... )` is a capture group, which will store what's inside if there's a match. Try to limit the use of those as much as possible since it consumes more memory your script/program would otherwise use without it.

`[ ... ]` is a character class which will match any characters mentioned inside. A lot of regex meta characters lose their meaning inside, and character classes have its own metacharacters: `^` which here would mean the opposite of the characters if placed at the beginning of the character class; and `-` to mean a range of characters if it's not excaped or at the extremities of the character class.

`[^ ... ]` as mentioned above is a negated class, which will match all characters except those in the character class.

`(?= ... )` is a positive lookahead which will allow a match only if the pattern inside matches what follows the previous match, without counting them in the match themself.

`(?<= ... )` is a positive lookbehind which will allow a match only if the pattern inside matches what precedes the following match, without counting them in the match themself.

---

From those, if you don't want to get empty matches, use either:

```
@([^@]+)@
```

Or:

```
(?<=@)[^@]+(?=@)
```

Since the `@(.+?)@` form will also allow `@` characters in the match.

Comment: @GM-XileGM-Xile Added more in-depth explanation to regex characters, groups and classes.